# iOS 8.3 Facebook error Not logged In

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, cocoa-touch

I'am sharing a NSString and NSURL, using the native UIActivityViewController

The user is logged in into Facebook both in Settings and also in the Facebook App

but after iOS 8.3 i'am getting this error... moreover, on older devices, the dialog confirmation is obscured by the keyboard, making it impossible to confirm or decline

[image]

```
UIActivityViewController *vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:items applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact];
vc.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

if (IsUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    vc.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.navigationController.view;
}
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a bug that went out in Version 29 of the Facebook application. We (Facebook) are working on a fix and hope that it will ship soon.

Comment: thanks, please also consider this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881531/ios-8-3-and-later-facebook-share-text-not-inserted?noredirect=1#comment47907013_29881531

Comment: Do you have any news regarding this issue Brian ?

Thanks